# Create User Account on Persistent Live USB Drive

Tags: usb, persistence

I created a persistent live drive with Ubuntu 16.04.1 using mkusb.
It does boot into the live user session account.
I tried to create a new user and gave it admin privileges.
But it behaves strangely, for example firefox and thunderbird are not opening and shutdown is not possible.

Is it possible with a persistent drive to create a user account or
set up a encrypted home and password prompt at boot for the live user session account?

Comment: Anybody with an idea?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I have created such an account, and at least one other person has done it too. I did it while running the persistent live system and *macho3* did it via chroot.

See these links

[Posts #428-432 in 'Howto make USB boot drives'](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073&page=22&p=13558751#post13558751)

[Post #708 # in 'Howto make USB boot drives' - Persistent live drive with a standard user, that cannot mount internal drives](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073&page=71&p=13670206#post13670206)

> #### Persistent live drive with a standard user, that cannot mount internal drives
>
> I made a persistent live drive with mkusb from
>   ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso, which has the longest support of the
>   present iso files.
>
> A standard user ID (alongside the normal live system's user 'ubuntu')
>   cannot run programs that need sudo: 'standard is not in the sudoers
>   file. This incident will be reported.' Partitions on the internal
>   drive are not mounted. To mount them, you need `sudo` permissions both
>   for `mount` and `udisksctl`.
>
> *The persistent live system will boot into the ubuntu user, and you log
>   out in order to switch to the standard user.*
>
> #### Encrypted home
>
> It is possible to create the standard user ID with encrypted home and
>   login with a [good] password. This can be done easily, if the program
>   users-admin is installed by activating the repository universe and
>   installing the package gnome-system-tools.
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository universe
> sudo apt update
> sudo apt install gnome-system-tools
> ```
>
> Tick the box according to the screenshot in order to create the new user
>   with encrypted home.
>
> [image]
>
> *The computer should be shut down or rebooted after using the encrypted
>   home.* Otherwise the live user (or another user) gets access to
>   encrypted data.
>
> #### Persistent live drive with a standard user and a user with administration permissions
>
> I made a persistent live drive with mkusb from
>   ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso, which is a newer LTS iso file, in
>   order to test that these tasks work with more than one iso file.
>
> In some computers, the system may leave you with a black screen after
>   logging in (after a logout). This might depend on the graphics driver.
>   If it happens, you can do something with the mouse or keyboard to get
>   to the desktop. If still no luck you can enter a text screen and then
>   return to the graphics screen with the hotkey combinations
>
> Ctrl + Alt + F1   Ctrl + Alt + F7
>
> It is possible to create another user ID with administration
>   permissions, that can manage system tasks, for example install and
>   upgrade program packages (if you want to separate the tasks because of
>   security reasons). One (or both) user ID(s) can be made with encrypted
>   home if you wish.
>
> With these two user IDs it will be possible to remove the live
>   system's normal user 'ubuntu'. You can do it from the user ID with
>   administration permissions after killing the processes that are
>   running with the user 'ubuntu'
>
> ```
> ps -Af | grep ubuntu  # identify which processes to kill   
> sudo kill <the PID numbers that you found (without any brackets)>  
>
> sudo deluser ubuntu
> ```
>
> After that you can also remove the content in the 'casper-rw'
>   partition (or file) concerning the deleted user (if you wish), but
>   there is probably not much data, so not very important unless you
>   suspect there is some confidential data.
>
> Now after removing the live system's normal user 'ubuntu', *the
>   persistent live system will boot to the login screen, and you can
>   select which user ID to log in to, the standard user or the user with
>   administration permissions.* I like this behavior, and I think it is
>   worth the extra effort (compared to a system with a standard user
>   alongside the normal live system's user 'ubuntu').
>
> #### Backup is important
>
> Frequent backup is important, because it is a
>
> - persistent live system (makes it sensitive)
> - an encrypted system (makes it difficult to repair/recover).
>
> See this link: [Backup and restore of persistent overlay
>   data](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent#Backup_and_restore_of_persistent_overlay_data)
>
> #### Security - turn off swapping
>
> If this kind of system finds a swap partition in the internal drive,
>   it will probably use it, and might leave traces that are not
>   encrypted. So please turn off swapping if there is a linux swap
>   partition in an internal drive in the computer, where you are running
>   the system.
>
> You must log in or 'su' into the user ID with administration
>   permissions, 'guru', to turn off swapping
>
> ```
> su - guru
> /sbin/swapon -s  # check
> sudo /sbin/swapoff -a
> /sbin/swapon -s  # check
> exit
> ```
>
> Comparing this kind of persistent live system to an installed system
>   (in a USB pendrive in both cases),
>
> Advantage:
>
> - more portable (than an installed system).
>
> Disadvantages:
>
> - less stable (than an installed system).
> - less secure (encrypted home is less secure than encrypted disk, which is possible with an installed system). But it might be secure
>     enough.